# How to fix file system corrupted usb (USB is not detecting)

Tags: usb, mount, filesystem

My USB flash drive has been corrupted and I really need it to work, I have tried to list the devices with command

```
lsblk
```

But it's showing only my hard disk and when I try to mount it with terminal commands its showing `No medium found` message please help me to fix this issue.

[image: Screenshot provided]

Comment: The drive is listed as /dev/sdc. If there is nothing on the drive of importance try zeroing it with dd. So "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc" without the quotes of course. You dont get any feedback during the process, so just wait to be returned to a command prompt.

Comment: @hatterman but I want to recover the data also. it has some important files

Comment: No backup of the important files ? Hate to sound like a #&@# but never use a USB stick for important files. Anyway .... If you cant mount it this will be tough. Are you sure it isnt encrypted ? Also, take a look at photorec, It might be able to work with raw disk, not sure.

Comment: @hatterman photorec can't detect the USB. so I think it's better to zeroing the USB, I couldn't find any other solution

Comment: @hatterman when i am try to run this command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc` I got the same error `dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdc’: No medium found`

Comment: I think its time to throw the USB pen in the bin. They are not expensive, you can get a replacement from Amazon. When did you last access the data on the pen ?